# Content beneath fixed AppBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Probably a basic question, but I couldn't find any example in the documentation. Using `material-ui-next` *beta.30*. I have the following:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as mui from 'material-ui';
import 'typeface-roboto';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <mui.Reboot />
      <mui.AppBar color="primary" position="fixed">
        <mui.Toolbar>
          <mui.Typography color="inherit" type="title">
            My Title
          </mui.Typography>
        </mui.Toolbar>
      </mui.AppBar>
      <mui.Paper>
        My Content
      </mui.Paper>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

And I want the `mui.Paper` content appear *beneath* the *AppBar*, and not hidden by it. Is there a component I'm missing somewhere?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your content is on screen, but covered up by the `AppBar`. You can use `theme.mixins.toolbar` to load information about the app bar height and shift your content accordingly:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  // Load app bar information from the theme
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
});
```

And then create a `div` above your content to shift your content accordingly:

```
<Paper>
  <div className={classes.toolbar} />
    MyContent will be shifted downwards by the div above. If you remove 
    the div, your content will disappear under the app bar.
</Paper>
```

What's happening here is that `theme.mixins.toolbar` is loading information about the `AppBar` dimensions into your styles. Then, applying that information to the `div` sizes the `div` so that it's exactly the right height for shifting your content down the screen.

Here's a full working example:

```
import React from 'react';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Reboot from 'material-ui/Reboot';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

const styles = (theme) => ({
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
});

const App = (props) => {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Reboot />
      <AppBar color="primary" position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography color="inherit" type="title">
            My Title
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Paper>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        MyContent will be shifted downwards by the div above. If you remove 
        the div, your content will disappear under the app bar.
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Comment: I had hoped there was a more elegant solution than this, but this'll do. Thanks!

Comment: @RoelvanUden I found a more rigorous solution to this problem than just adding a constant padding to the content. I've updated my answer accordingly. I know this is a bit late but hopefully it can still help you out!

Comment: I don't really consider this a solution, looks a lot like a hack... Like going back to the "clearfix" days... I mean, why does the problem happen in the first place? Why doesn't the content follow the normal flow?

Comment: This is a perfect solution as it respects defined breakpoints where the toolbar's height changes.

Comment: `Why doesn't the content follow the normal flow?` Because the AppBar is _fixed_, not _relative_ nor _sticky_.

Comment: The answer below is better

Answer (score 84):

Just use `position="sticky"` instead of `position="fixed"` for your AppBar.

Comment: My app bar then becomes thing (like it has padding on either side)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Comment: Just a note for people using `Drawer` along with an `AppBar` you have to do something like `<div flexDirection="row"> <YourDrawer/> <div flexDirection="column"><YourStickyAppBar /><YourContent /></div> </div>`

Comment: sticky didn't work for me, most likely due to a browser issue. I used `Jules` solution. `5.2.1`

Answer (score 32):

Simply add an empty *Toolbar* after *AppBar*:

```
<AppBar>
  <Toolbar>
    ...toolbar content...
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>

<Toolbar /> // <- does the trick
```

Source:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16844#issuecomment-517205129

Comment: I added style={{ marginBottom: 20}} to appbar and got the necessary margin

Comment: By adding a fixed value to the marginBottom you'll probably be breaking the interface for different devices (i.e, mobile vs desktop). The trick with the Toolbar above works like a charm.

Comment: This is great for bottom toolbars too, thanks!

Comment: tried this with the `5.2.1` and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 12):

The [Elevate App Bar example](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#elevate-app-bar) just adds an empty `Toolbar`:

```
export default function ElevateAppBar(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <ElevationScroll {...props}>
        <AppBar>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6">Scroll to Elevate App Bar</Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </ElevationScroll>
      <Toolbar />  // <-- The important part.
      <Container>
        <Box my={2}>
          {[...new Array(12)]
            .map(
              () => `Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.`,
            )
            .join('\n')}
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer didn't seem to work for me but this did. Thanks

Comment: This answer also worked for me. The accepted answer seems to have been valid long ago, but for the latest version of material-ui as of today, this answer worked well. And without having to do other hacks, adding a single line of code to push content down seems the most intuitive way of pushing page content.

Comment: I was wondering while reading the docs why that 2nd empty toolbar. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

None of these solutions (completely) worked for me...

The size of my AppBar changes on window resize to-and-from mobile(960px). The `theme.mixins.toolbar` solution returns a static theme height, which left extra space below my AppBar. The `position="sticky"` solution puts the AppBar inline, making it inaccessible if you are not at the top of the page.

Here is my solution:

```
export default function () {
  const nav = useRef();
  const [navHeight, setNavHeight] = useState(0);
  const [isMobile, setMobile] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    nav.current && setNavHeight(nav.current.clientHeight);
  }, [isMobile]);

  const checkIsMobile = () => (window.innerWidth < 960 ? true : false);
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.onresize = () => isMobile !== checkIsMobile && setMobile(checkIsMobile);
  } 

  return (
    <>
      <AppBar ref={nav}></AppBar>
      <div style={{ paddingTop: `${navHeight}px`}} />
    </>
  )
}
```

The useLayoutEffect hook fires when the window.innerWidth crosses the threshold of 960px, triggering setNavHeight, which is used to set the paddingTop on the dummy `<div/>` below the `<AppBar/>`.

This solution works with Material-UI 4.11.0 and Next.js 9.4.4 as of 2020/06/31.

Answer (score 1):

This question is about "content" beneath the fixed appbar. If by content is meant only the very first top of the page, then all answers above are valid, but if by content is also meant links anchors and scrolling to elements ids, headings,... which is pretty much common in most pages, then neither of the provided solution is satisfactory. CSS do have a good fix for that which is `scroll-padding-top`:

```css
html {
    scroll-padding-top: 80px;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding-top